# How to filter relationship in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a Post entity and inside of it I have a relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="comment", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL", nullable=true)
 */
private Comment $comment;
```

I'm fetching multiple Posts and with each Post entity I only get one Comment entity.
I need to fetch comments which have "state": "published".

I tried to do it with join:

```
$qb
->leftJoin(Comment::class,
    'comments',
    Join::WITH,
    'post.comment = comments.id AND comments.state = :publishedState'
)
->setParameter('publishedState', 'published')
```

It does not work, it always returns one comment regardless of state.

So I need to fetch Post entites but if Comment.state != 'published' then Comment relationship will be empty, otherwise it won't. How can I filter comments by state?

Laravel has this:

```
Posts::with(['comments' => function($query) {
  $query->where('state', 'published');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be Many comments instead of only one on each post ?

Comment: Don't worry about that atm

Comment: First correct your relationship mapping it should be `OneToMany`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the relationship to be a OneToMany relationship.
The post entity should read something along the lines of:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post")
 */
private $comments;
```

With the comment entity looking something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private Post $post;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split join and [where](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#line-number-5775ab09aefa638b14c776a733b4b61d2e324b74-55) in two separated methods:

```
$qb
->leftJoin(Comment::class,
'comments',
Join::WITH,
'post.comment = comments.id'
)
->andWhere('comments.state = :publishedState')
->setParameter('publishedState', 'published')
```